# How to use routerLink and query params in ts file

Tags: angular

How to use `routerLink` and query params in typescript file?

[image: screenshot of vscode]

Comment: You don't use routerLink in ts-file - inject Router in your constructor and use that instead.

Comment: Please give code as text instead of an image..